# jQuery: Unable to select class names that begin with string followed by hyphen

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<a class="btn btndialog-save" href="#">Save</a>
<a class="btn btndialog-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
<a class="btn btndialog-whatever"href="#">Whatever</a>

<p></p>
```

On click, I want to be able to get the class name part followed by hyphen (-) which I'm trying to do as follows but doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[class|='btndialog']").on('click', function(){
        var $dialog = this.className.match(/btndialog-/)[1];
        $("p").text($dialog);
    });
});
```

Can someone please tell me where this is going wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/tc31ru50/

Comment: Just asking why you would need to do this. There may be another way that is much easier.

Comment: @ultimatecoder use this `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[class*='btndialog']").on('click', function(){
        var $dialog = this.className.match(/btndialog-[a-z]*/).toString().split('-');
   
        $("p").text($dialog[1]);
    });
});`

Comment: @ultimatecode for more info about selectors [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[class|='btn btndialog']").on('click', function(){      
        var index = this.className.indexOf('-');
        if(index) {
          $("p").text(this.className.substring(index+1));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btndialog-save" href="#">Save</a>
<a class="btn btndialog-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
<a class="btn btndialog-whatever"href="#">Whatever</a>

<p></p>
```

Note : ref - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|=”value”]
```

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).

If you wish to use the generic selector try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on('click', function(){      
        var index = this.className.indexOf('-');
        if(index) {
          $("p").text(this.className.substring(index+1));
        }
    });
});
```

If you are looking for any classnames in between try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on('click', function(){            
        var index = this.className.indexOf('-');
        if(index) {
          var dd = this.className.substring(index+1);
          var lastIndex = dd.indexOf(' ');
          $("p").text(dd.substring(0,(lastIndex>0)?lastIndex:dd.length));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But with your solution, I have to ensure that the classname with the hyphen is towards the end and I have no control over that.

Comment: @ultimatecoder if that is the case, use the common classname "btn" as selector, rest of the things will work as expected, see my edit

Comment: Still the same issue, if I have a third classname after the class with the hyphen, I get the third class name in my string https://jsfiddle.net/9qcgjw7e/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to work with such a complex selectors. It may impact performance and make your jQuery code non-readable.

You can simply make it:

```
<a class="btn btndialog btndialog-save" href="#">Save</a>
<a class="btn btndialog btndialog-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
<a class="btn btndialog btndialog-whatever"href="#">Whatever</a>
```

It doesn't worsen readability or supportability, but now you can do:

```
$(".btndialog")
```

Moreover, you are now able to apply common CSS style logics like "all btndialogs should use another font" - done in a single line of CSS.

That's what most of plugins and CSS frameworks actually do.
For example, bootstrap has:

```
btn btn-default
modal modal-sm
alert alert-success
glyphicon glyphicon-ok
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but there is probably a better way to accomplish what you need:

```
  $("a ").on('click', function(){
   //get the class
   var str = $(this).attr('class')
   //spit the class at the - and take the string at index[1]
   var x = str.split('-')[1]; 

   $("p").text(x)
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjh8kysx/

Comment: Thanks! But with your solution, I have to ensure that the classname with the hyphen is towards the end and I have no control over that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change order of class `class="btn btndialog-save"` to `class="btndialog-save btn"`.. otherwise take other class and apply event on that..like `$('.specific-class').click`

```
<a class="btndialog-save btn" href="#">Save</a>
<a class="btndialog-delete btn" href="#">Delete</a>
<a class="btndialog-whatever btn"href="#">Whatever</a>

<p></p>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[class|='btndialog']").on('click', function(){
        var $dialog = this.className.match(/btndialog-/)[1];
        $("p").text($dialog);
    });
});
```

Better way to take specific class and apply click event.

Comment: I can't make it a specific class and I can't control the order of the class names.

Comment: In that case.. we should apply condition for click event. follow below URL may be it will help you